# Change language of date. Django

Tags: python, django, date

I would like to know if there is a way to change the language of a date when we render it (the same way we can change the format: {{mydate|date:"d F Y - H:i"}}).

I looked at the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date   but i didn't find anything.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the locale before rendering it as a string. Then change it back after. Although, I'm not sure why you want to have a date in a language different from your other output. Maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish with this, first. There is no built-in way to do it simply formatting the date.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just try to display a date in a different language from the other dates. Let say I have {{mydate1}} and {{mydate2}} in english and {{mydate3}} in french (the three dates are different dates).

Comment: Gotcha, for this, you could suggest creating a custom template tag/filter. Output your dates in the template like {{ mydate1|displayEnglish }} and {{ mydate3|displayFrench }}. In the tag/filter you could change the locale and translate the date as a string. However, I think this should be done in the view. For mydate1 and mydate2 have the English locale and translate, then change locale for and translate mydate3. Since there are stored as strings and passed to the template, they should retain their language. Not totally sure this will work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

In django, you need change the language in you `setting.py` like that:

`LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-PE'`

for this example, i'm from Perú.